# Retopology - Snap With Subsurf?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, snapping

I'm using snap to re-topologize a mesh. I also have a subsurf applied, but it drops the vertices below the target's surface.

Is there a way I could have the "applied" subsurf vertices snap to the target surface properly?

I know I could subdivide, but I was hoping to keep the poly-count down.

Comment: You could use the [*Shrinkwrap* modifier](http://blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/deform/shrinkwrap.html)